# visio c# get RGB-Color from a layer

Tags: c#, colors, layer, visio

i try to get the current Color of a layer in an visio document as RGB. My problem are colors, that are not set with "RGB(1,2,3)" in the formula. There are some colors set, based on the current scheme. So there are colors with "255" (layer color not chosen) or "19" (the used color depends on the active scheme, eg. dark-gray).

I need a way to transform "19" to an RGB-scheme, depending on the current scheme and variant.

Heiko

Comment: doesnt this work for you ? Color c = Color.FromArgb(your integer value); which will give you your color in ARGB format and you easily extract the values of R G and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio has first 24 colors fixed. All others come in form of `RGB(R, G, B)` formula. The list of fixed colors can be obtained form `Document.Colors`. All in all, you could start with following:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

static Color GetLayerColor(Visio.Layer layer)
{
    var str = layer
        .CellsC[(short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visLayerColor]
        .ResultStrU[""];

    // case 1: fixed color
    int colorNum;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out colorNum))
    {
        var visioColor = layer.Document.Colors[colorNum];

        return Color.FromArgb(
            visioColor.Red, 
            visioColor.Green, 
            visioColor.Blue);
    }

    // case 2: RGB formula
    var m = Regex.Match(str, @"RGB\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)").Groups;

    return Color.FromArgb(
        int.Parse(m[1].Value), 
        int.Parse(m[2].Value), 
        int.Parse(m[3].Value)
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works with one little change. When no layer color was checked and chosen, then there is colorNum = 255 and no responding color in layer.Document.Colors[colorNum]. When this happens, i return Color.empty.